# Why does a reference to me in a function returns an object of type VBScriptTypeInfo?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Consider this code:

```
Function foo()
    Set foo = me
End Function

MsgBox TypeName(foo())
```

This displays the string `VBScriptTypeInfo`. Why?

Returning `me` from a function (standalone, not inside a class) seems to return a valid object:
`IsObject(foo())` returns `True`;
`(foo() Is Nothing)` returns `False`

Can we elaborate the returned `me` object in some way to make it useful?

Comment: just speculation, but is it the same as returning `this` from a similar function in JScript?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional Yes, `this` and `me` are kind of similar. However, in VBScript `me` is only used in objects while `this` in JavaScript has also use in functions. I love to find neat tricks in the limited language of VBScript and was wondering what `me` was doing in functions and if it could be useful for something.

Comment: Interesting that a) it took years until I discovered that question and b) there is a "me" identifier at all in the global scope. Is this true for non-asp VBScript scripts? Mmmh..

Comment: Completely strange: MsgBox TypeName (me) without any function definition involved returns, if executed in QTP, a string containing an integer. First run: "1", second run "2", and so on. In a function, it seems to be the same "me". Wtf?

Comment: And strange again: Just look at what "me" watched in QTPs debugger shows: An object instance with more stuff to explore. (If we ever find the time :-))

Comment: Worth a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec/32302212#32302212