# I want to hide the windows terminal every time I run a tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I'm running a tcl script that checks the difference between files:

```
package require twapi
proc diff {file1 file2} {
    set f1 [open $file1 "rb"]
    set f2 [open $file2 "rb"]
    try {
        while 1 {
            if {[read $f1 4096] ne [read $f2 4096]} {
                return 0
            } elseif {[eof $f1]} {
                # The same if we got to EOF at the same time
                return [eof $f2]
            } elseif {[eof $f2]} {
                return 0
            }
        }
    } finally {
        close $f1
        close $f2
    }
}
```

I need to run this procedure in the background, but everytime I run it, it opens a windows terminal. I tried using a vbs script and it works:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "diff.tcl",0,True
```

But I need to pass the arguments to the diff.tcl from another program so running as a vbs script is not useful.

Comment: I suspect this is partially to do with the associations for the Open action of the `.tcl` filetype, but I forget the details and I'm on a totally different platform so I can't just inspect directly.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that's the case. I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

What Donal said.

Specifically, your installation of Windows™ supposedly
is set up to associate `tclsh.exe` to run files with `.tcl`
extension in their names. (One way to learn what's
the association(s) is running [`assoc.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc); also see [`ftype.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype)).

`tclsh.exe` (the name stems from "The **Tcl Sh**ell") is
an application compiled with the so-called "console subsystem"
flag set on (a flag in the special header contained metainformation of an executable file on Windows™).
When the OS runs such an application it notices it needs
a console and so it spawns one and then runs the application
in it.

#### The solutions

- Try using the `Run` method of the `WScript.Shell`
  object and pass 0 as its second argument to hide the
  created window; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298415/720999) for more.
- Tcl gets shipped with another interpreter, called `wish.exe`
  (a portmanue of "The **Wi**ndowed **Sh**ell") which differs
  from `tclsh.exe` by the fact it has Tk automatically available (loaded).

  You might want to explicitly run your script using `wish.exe`
  and passing it the pathname of your script as an argument.

  You might need to use `wm withdraw .` as the first command in your script to hide the main window created by Tk.

Comment: If you don't do any long running stuff and don't need the event loop, it might be easier to just `exit` at the end.

Comment: Oh, I failed to comprehend you are _already_ using wscript.shell's Run. So the question is: _what from_ are you starting your Tcl script? Is is a program? If yes, what programming language it's written in?

Comment: I'm asking because what wscript.shell does it no magic: it basically calls [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) while tweaking the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_startupinfoa) parameter  passed to it in a way so that the process's window is initially hidden.

Comment: I found the solution: I was calling the script from an autohotkey script using the command "Run, tclsh diff.tcl". I just needed to add ,,hide at the end and that way it will not show the command prompt. The problem I have with wish.exe is that when I instruct wm withdraw . it loses focus from the current windows.

Comment: @milarepa, ah, that lovely [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)! ;-) Please next time state clear what the real original problem is, and only present your solution to it and a new problem it caused last.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about outputting the results to a temporary file and having whatever is downstream look for that file? You could then use your VBS method of keying the script. It's messy but it would work.