# Silently run EXE with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have created a script which checks for the idle time using a program `MousePos.exe` and pushes the response back to itself to work out whether there has been any mouse movement. This all works fine, however everytime the `MousePos.exe` runs it flashes on the screen and I want to hide this. I have no idea how to do this, I expected it would be quite simple.

I was advised I need to Use the `WshShell` object's `Run` method instead of the `WshScriptExec` object but I have no idea how to do this and still read in the response from the EXE.

```
Function execStdOut(cmd)
    Dim goWSH : Set goWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim aRet: Set aRet = goWSH.Exec(cmd)
    execStdOut = aRet.StdOut.ReadAll()
End Function

'wait 2 seconds for things to calm now
WScript.Sleep 2000

'get initial Mouse XY
MPOS = execStdOut("cmd /c C:\Windows\MousePos.exe")

WScript.Sleep 10000 '10 seconds

'set initial idle counter
Idle = 0

Do While forever = 0
    OLD  = MPOS
    MPOS = execStdOut("cmd /c C:\Windows\MousePos.exe")
    If OLD = MPOS Then
        Idle = Idle + 1
        If idle = 12 Then '12 x 10 seconds for 2 minute timeout
            idle = 0
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            objshell.Run "C:\Windows\IERestart_countdown.hta", 1, True
        End If
    Else
        idle = 0
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 10000 ' 10 seconds
Loop
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32297699/2165759).