# Get output from command line in VB6

Tags: vb6

i am using this .Cls file and a command using 7zip to extract specific file from a zip.
my single file gets extracted how ever i need to add if statement to se if my file was found so that i can exit sub it 
can this piece of code be modifed to add own code 
DOSOutputs.cls

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PeekMessageA" (lpMsg As MsgType, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function TranslateMessage Lib "user32" (ByRef lpMsg As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function DispatchMessage Lib "user32" Alias "DispatchMessageW" (ByRef lpMsg As Any) As Long
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
Private Type MsgType
    hWnd        As Long
    message     As Long
    wParam      As Long
    lParam      As Long
    Time        As Long
    pt          As POINTAPI
End Type
Private Const PM_NOREMOVE           As Long = 0&
Private Const PM_REMOVE             As Long = 1&
'
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
'The CreatePipe function creates an anonymous pipe,
'and returns handles to the read and write ends of the pipe.
Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" ( _
    phReadPipe As Long, _
    phWritePipe As Long, _
    lpPipeAttributes As Any, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

'Used to read the the pipe filled by the process create
'with the CretaProcessA function
Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hFile As Long, _
    ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, _
    lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, _
    ByVal lpOverlapped As Any) As Long

'Structure used by the CreateProcessA function
Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

'Structure used by the CreateProcessA function
Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As Long
    lpDesktop As Long
    lpTitle As Long
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Long
    hStdInput As Long
    hStdOutput As Long
    hStdError As Long
End Type

'Structure used by the CreateProcessA function
Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As Long
    hThread As Long
    dwProcessID As Long
    dwThreadID As Long
End Type

'This function launch the the commend and return the relative process
'into the PRECESS_INFORMATION structure
Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal lpApplicationName As Long, _
    ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
    lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
    ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, _
    ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
    lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
    lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

'Close opened handle
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hHandle As Long) As Long

'Consts for the above functions
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = &H100&
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = &H1


Private mCommand As String          'Private variable for the CommandLine property
Private mOutputs As String          'Private variable for the ReadOnly Outputs property

'Event that notify the temporary buffer to the object
Public Event ReceiveOutputs(CommandOutputs As String)

'This property set and get the DOS command line
'It's possible to set this property directly from the
'parameter of the ExecuteCommand method
Public Property Let CommandLine(DOSCommand As String)
    mCommand = DOSCommand
End Property

Public Property Get CommandLine() As String
    CommandLine = mCommand
End Property

'This property ReadOnly get the complete output after
'a command execution
Public Property Get Outputs()
    Outputs = mOutputs
End Property

Public Function ExecuteCommand(Optional CommandLine As String) As String
    Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION     'Process info filled by CreateProcessA
    Dim ret As Long                     'long variable for get the return value of the
                                        'API functions
    Dim start As STARTUPINFO            'StartUp Info passed to the CreateProceeeA
                                        'function
    Dim sa As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES       'Security Attributes passeed to the
                                        'CreateProcessA function
    Dim hReadPipe As Long               'Read Pipe handle created by CreatePipe
    Dim hWritePipe As Long              'Write Pite handle created by CreatePipe
    Dim lngBytesread As Long            'Amount of byte read from the Read Pipe handle
    Dim strBuff As String * 256         'String buffer reading the Pipe

    'if the parameter is not empty update the CommandLine property
    If Len(CommandLine) > 0 Then
        mCommand = CommandLine
    End If

    'if the command line is empty then exit whit a error message
    If Len(mCommand) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Command Line empty", vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Create the Pipe
    sa.nLength = Len(sa)
    sa.bInheritHandle = 1&
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
    ret = CreatePipe(hReadPipe, hWritePipe, sa, 0)

    If ret = 0 Then
        'If an error occur during the Pipe creation exit
        MsgBox "CreatePipe failed. Error: " & Err.LastDllError, vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Launch the command line application
    start.cb = Len(start)
    start.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES Or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    'set the StdOutput and the StdError output to the same Write Pipe handle
    start.hStdOutput = hWritePipe
    start.hStdError = hWritePipe
    'Execute the command
    ret& = CreateProcessA(0&, mCommand, sa, sa, 1&, _
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc)

    If ret <> 1 Then
        'if the command is not found ....
        MsgBox "File or command not found", vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Now We can ... must close the hWritePipe
    ret = CloseHandle(hWritePipe)
    mOutputs = ""

    'Read the ReadPipe handle
    Do
        ret = ReadFile(hReadPipe, strBuff, 256, lngBytesread, 0&)
        mOutputs = mOutputs & Left(strBuff, lngBytesread)
        'Send data to the object via ReceiveOutputs event
        RaiseEvent ReceiveOutputs(Left(strBuff, lngBytesread))
        'Pause 0.02
       FastDoEvents
    Loop While ret <> 0

    'Close the opened handles
    ret = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
    ret = CloseHandle(proc.hThread)
    ret = CloseHandle(hReadPipe)

    'Return the Outputs property with the entire DOS output
    ExecuteCommand = mOutputs
End Function
Public Sub FastDoEvents()
    Dim uMsg As MsgType
    '
    Do While PeekMessage(uMsg, 0&, 0&, 0&, PM_REMOVE)   ' Reads and deletes message from queue.
        TranslateMessage uMsg                           ' Translates virtual-key messages into character messages.
        DispatchMessage uMsg                            ' Dispatches a message to a window procedure.
    Loop
End Sub
```

form1

```
Private WithEvents objDOS As DOSOutputs

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set objDOS = New DOSOutputs
End Sub
```

button command

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()
On Error Resume Next

    On Error GoTo errore
    objDOS.CommandLine = text6.text
    objDOS.ExecuteCommand
'If objDOS.Outputs = "41_gfx7.rom " Then
'Text1.Text = Text1.Text & objDOS.Outputs & vbNewLine
'End If
    Exit Sub
errore:
    MsgBox (Err.Description & " - " & Err.Source & " - " & CStr(Err.Number))

End Sub
```

text6.text has

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" x "C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" -o"C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *41_gfx7.rom -y
```

so now am trying to get the status from output using if statement to se if **41_gfx7.rom** was found so that i can exit the scan or sub as there is no need to scan further.
or maybe if you can help add better one it will be great,once the string is found exit sub it

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim objShell As New WshShell
Dim objExecObject As WshExec
Dim strText As String

Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(Text6.Text)
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream

    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Reply received: " & strText
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop
End Sub
```

text6 is my command

ok update

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" x "C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" -o"C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *41_gfx7.rom -y
```

i need to add list to this command according to https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/list.htm so that file names gets displayed in output data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following Microsoft article describes two methods that read the output of a command: [WSH: Running Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee156605(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

The simplest uses the StdOut property of the WshExec object:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 157.59.0.1")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
    If Instr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Reply received."
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

You can replace the `ping` command here with your `7z` command and read `StdOut` to see what your command returned.

Since you are doing this in VB6, you can add a reference (Projects menu > References) to **Windows Script Host Object Model** library and instantiate the objects with the proper types directly:

```
Dim objShell As New WshShell
Dim objExecObject As WshExec
Dim strText As String

Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 127.0.0.1")

Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream

    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Reply received: " & strText
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop
```

With this approach you don't need the DOSCommand.cls, you can simply use the WshShell object for all your operations.

Your `Command22_Click` would look like this:

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()

    On Error GoTo errore

    Dim objShell As New WshShell
    Dim objExecObject As WshExec
    Dim strText As String

    Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(text6.Text)

    Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream

        strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()

        ' Parse the text your 7z command returned here
        If InStr(strText, "41_gfx7.rom") > 0 Then
            Text1.Text = Text1.Text & strText & vbCrLf
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    Exit Sub

errore:
    MsgBox (Err.Description & " - " & Err.Source & " - " & CStr(Err.Number))
End Sub
```

Comment: i got Reply received: Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 can i add my cmd command? "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" x "C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" -o"C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *41_gfx7.rom -y

Comment: check post one below

Comment: You will have to tweak the code a little bit to make it work in your scenario but the answer demonstrates a solution for reading the output of the command line as you are trying to do.

Comment: If InStr(strText, "41_gfx7.rom") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Reply received: " & strText
        Exit Do
    End If  will the instr be accurate or pick up other similar ones and once it finds it will it exit search because cmd closes after file extraction

Comment: were we se the l or x , x is for extract now replacing that with l works but my extract lol

Comment: You don't really need to extract the files right? `l` should be sufficient to see if the file exists.

Comment: yes i needed to extract the file which is other part of my project sir. i scan through various zip names for specific file and if it contains the extract and stop process.

Comment: good answer. Would it be possible to run the .exec(..) command without a black command window having popped up for a short time?

Comment: @GeraldSchade see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec