# Read text from command prompt in UFT

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt, uft14

Can I capture text from the command prompt in UFT? How could I capture text from the command prompt in UFT for validation purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StdOut` property of the `Exec` object to read text from the command window:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sCommand = "ping 127.0.0.1"
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c " & sCommand)

Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    sText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop
```

Replace the command text with your command, exactly how you would type it in the command prompt.

Take a look at extra examples in these questions:

[Get output from command line in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661934/get-output-from-command-line-in-vb6/58662058#58662058)

[Run Command Line & Command From VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087470/run-command-line-command-from-vbs)