# How to remove the shell pop up in shell.exec in VBA?

Tags: r, excel, vba, shell, cmd

I am trying to call the R script from the VBA code and I am using `VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec` which shows the pop up of the shell window and then it closes. My output is working fine but I don't want any window popup which can be achieved using `VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run` command. The problem here is that, I am not able to convert my command so that it is executed with `VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run`. The idea with `.Run` is to print the output in an output file and then read the output file.

```
'Function to call the Rscript to convert any case to title case
Public Function ToTitleCase(Text As String) As String
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim path As String
    
    path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\Rscript.exe"" ""S:\01) Analytics\Temp\AnalystInput\ConvertToTitleCase.R"" -t " + """" + Text + """"
    ToTitleCase = shell.Exec(path).StdOut.ReadAll
    
End Function
```

This code is working fine. The code I want to do is below:

```
'Function to call the Rscript to convert any case to title case
Public Function ToTitleCase(Text As String) As String
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim path As String
    
    'path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\Rscript.exe"" ""S:\01) Analytics\Temp\AnalystInput\ConvertToTitleCase.R"" -t " + """" + Text + """"
    'ToTitleCase = shell.Exec(path).StdOut.ReadAll
    
    path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\Rscript.exe"" ""S:\01) Analytics\Temp\AnalystInput\ConvertToTitleCase.R"" -t " + """" + Text + """" + " > " + """C:\Users\AnalystInput\output.txt"""
    Debug.Print path
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        ' Pass 0 as the second parameter to hide the window...
        .Run path, 0, True
    End With
    
    ' Read the output and remove the file when done...
    Dim strOutput
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strOutput = .OpenTextFile("C:\Users\AnalystInput\output.txt").ReadAll()
        '.DeleteFile "c:\out.txt"
    End With
    
End Function
```

I have taken the print of the `path` and it comes out  `"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\Rscript.exe" "S:\01) Analytics\Temp\AnalystInput\ConvertToTitleCase.R" -t "VishalKumar" > "C:\Users\AnalystInput\output.txt"` which works fine in windows command prompt.

Can any please help me here.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec) very similar question.

Comment: @VishalSharma : I took the liberty to add the _cmd_ tag, because _shell_ without specification of the kind of shell, implies POSIX shell.

Comment: @BenMega I have tried with that code and I am following it only. But the problem I am facing is in creating the command to pass to .Run path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\Rscript.exe"" ""S:\01) Analytics\Temp\AnalystInput\ConvertToTitleCase.R"" -t " + """" + Text + """" + " > " + """C:\Users\AnalystInput\output.txt""" 

I am not sure that I am creating the command correctly or not. I have taken the print of the command and runs it separately on cmd and it works fine but not with .Run