How to find R_HOME with VBA Environ
I can find the path to R by using Sys.getenv() like so:
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1"

However, I am trying to find the R_HOME with the Environ function from Excel VBA with a subroutine something like:
Sub findR()
Dim a As String
a = Environ$("R_HOME")
MsgBox a
End Sub

The message box returns empty. R_HOME is in the environment but for some reason Environ can't find it. See a screenshot attached showing R_HOME in the environment. Could someone point me in the right direction to find R_HOME with Environ VBA?


This VBA function, GetREnviron, is designed to retrieve environment variables from an R installation, such as R_HOME, by running a small R script through the Windows command line.
Parameter EnvName: The function takes one parameter, EnvName, which is the name of the environment variable you want to retrieve (e.g., "R_HOME").
R Script Construction: The function dynamically creates a small R script (Rscript -e "cat(Sys.getenv('EnvName'))") to retrieve the value of the specified environment variable using R's Sys.getenv function.
Shell Execution: It uses the WScript.Shell object to execute the R script and capture the output (StdOut.ReadAll). This output is the value of the environment variable.
Trimming Output: Any extra whitespace or newline characters are trimmed from the output.
Error Handling: If something goes wrong (e.g., R is not installed, or the variable doesn't exist), the function returns a generic error message, "Error: Unable to retrieve EnvName".
This approach allows for dynamically retrieving any R environment variable by passing its name as an argument to the function.
Function GetREnviron(Name As String, Optional TrimResult As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim RScript As String
    Dim ShellOutput As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        
    Rem R script to print the specified environment variable
    RScript = "Rscript -e ""cat(Sys.getenv('" & Name & "'))"""
        
    Rem Create a Shell object
    With VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Rem Run the R script and capture the output
        ShellOutput = .Exec(RScript).StdOut.ReadAll
    End With
        
    Rem Trim any extra whitespace from the output
    GetREnviron = IIf(TrimResult, Trim(ShellOutput), ShellOutput)
        
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    GetREnviron = "Error: Unable to retrieve " & Name
End Function

I've updated the code to store the environmental variable.  This will avoid having to use WScript.Shell more than once per variable per machine.
Function GetREnviron(Name As String, Optional UpdateSetting As Boolean = False, Optional TrimResult As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim RScript As String
    Dim ShellOutput As String
    Dim SavedSettings As Variant
    Dim StoredValue As String
    Dim AppName As String
    Dim Section As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    AppName = "REnvironSettings"  ' Application name for SaveSetting
    Section = "EnvironmentVars"    ' Section to store environment variables
    
    ' Retrieve all saved settings
    SavedSettings = GetAllSettings(AppName, Section)
    
    ' Check if the variable is already saved and UpdateSetting is False
    If Not UpdateSetting And Not IsEmpty(SavedSettings) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        StoredValue = GetSetting(AppName, Section, Name, "")
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        If Len(StoredValue) > 0 Then
            GetREnviron = StoredValue
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' If not saved or UpdateSetting is True, run the R script to get the environment variable
    RScript = "Rscript -e ""cat(Sys.getenv('" & Name & "'))"""
        
    ' Create a Shell object and capture the output
    With VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        ShellOutput = .Exec(RScript).StdOut.ReadAll
    End With
        
    ' Trim any extra whitespace from the output
    ShellOutput = IIf(TrimResult, Trim(ShellOutput), ShellOutput)
    
    ' Save the retrieved environment variable value
    SaveSetting AppName, Section, Name, ShellOutput
    
    ' Return the result
    GetREnviron = ShellOutput
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    GetREnviron = "Error: Unable to retrieve " & Name
End Function

Addendum
It turns out we can get R_HOME by reading the Windows Registry.
Rem Function to get the value from the registry
Function GetRegistryValue(keyPath As String, valueName As String) As String
    Dim Reg As Object
    Dim Key As String
    Dim Value As String

    Rem Create WScript.Shell to interact with the registry
    Set Reg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Rem Try to read the registry value
    On Error Resume Next
    Value = Reg.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" & keyPath & "\" & valueName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Rem Return the result (the registry value)
    GetRegistryValue = Value
End Function

Rem Function to get the R installation directory path
Function GetR_HOME() As String
    Rem Call GetRegistryValue to retrieve the R "InstallPath" from the registry
    GetR_HOME = GetRegistryValue("SOFTWARE\R-core\R", "InstallPath")
End Function


It works really well @TinMan . This is a great idea!!!!  Is there a way to hide the command prompt when executing VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")?

I am getting an error message. Is going to the error handler after running the shell object.

Sorry about that @Salvador. I removed the new code because I'm unable to test the code because I don't have R installed.   You might consider storing the path  use SaveSetting and retrieve it using GetSetting.  This way you would only have to use GetREnviron once.

Thanks for your help @TinMan. I will play around with it.

Your code shouldn’t need the Trim() (and users might want to preserve whitespace if the environment variable contains any).

Thanks @KonradRudolph.  I added an optional parameter to give the users a choice.

I modified the code in multiple different ways and couldn't find the way to hide the command prompt

@Salvador The prompt is unfortunately unavoidable with this method, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298415/1968

@KonradRudolph WScript.Shell.Run has a parameter to hide the window.  Could we use it to write the result to a emp file and then read the file?  I can't test it because I don't have R Script installed.

@TinMan Yes, Run will work but, as the linked answer says, it doesn’t support capturing stdout, so you will need to go the detour via a file.

@KonradRudolph thanks for the feedback.  I used AI to modify my code but I cannot test it.

@TinMan, Unfortunately, none of the two latest suggestions worked as I still get an error message on ShellOutput = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(TempFile & ".out", 1).ReadAll. The TempFile that is created in the Temp folder reads cat(Sys.getenv('R_HOME')). Should it be without cat?

I also appears that OpenTextFile is not finding the TempFile with the .out extension.

Cat is needed to print to concatenate and print the output to either the Command Window or File destination.  It appears like we can use the WinAPI GetEnvironmentVariableA to retrieve the variables.  I added the new code snippet.  Let me know if it works so that I can cleanup my post.  Thanks

@TinMan, I get the same error. You have done enough and want to thank you for that. Ideally, I would like to hide it but I can live with it. The reason I want to hide it is because all of the process between R and Excel is automated and run behind the scenes, I wanted not to show that black window. Thanks so much for trying.

One last update.  It's been fun.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

@TinMan, it works but the black window pops up :(

@Salvador the window should only popup the first time.

Ahhh Yesss, it works now and the black window doesn't pop up anymore. This is a great workaround. Thank you so much again @TinMan for your help. Really appreciate it.

I will assume that the black window will pop up again when I update to a different version of R. I am using R 4.1.1 right now but soon will update to 4.4.1

You would need to reset the setting whenever the return value fails (is invalid).  GetREnviron(Name:="R_HOME", UpdateSetting As Boolean = True) .

Last question @TinMan, Where is StoredValue saved in the computer? In other words where GetREnviron retrieves the saved R path from?

@Salvador you're a genius!!  I was able to get R_HOME by reading the registry.

Better yet @TinMan. Thanks again for being so kind!!!!
